# Are contraction-sensitive graphs necessarily vertex-transitive?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

We say that a finite, simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is *contraction-sensitive* if collapsing any $2$ non-adjacent points increases the [Hadwiger number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_number). An example of such a graph [is the icosahedron](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325655/contracting-non-adjacent-points-in-the-icosahedron).

Is every contraction-sensitive graph [vertex-transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph)?

Comment: If you pick one triangle of an icosahedron and link all its 3 vertices to an additional vertex, it seems to me that the resulting (still planar) graph is still contraction-sensitive. If someone could confirm that with Sage, it would be a counterexample.

Comment: I checked in Sage and @Wolfgang's example works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pick one triangle of an icosahedron and link all its 3 vertices to an additional vertex, the resulting graph is still contraction-sensitive, as @David Roberson has kindly checked in Sage. So this is a counterexample.