# Reference on graphs such that contracting 2 non-adjacent vertices increases the Hadwiger number

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is a finite simple graph. Let $h(G)$ denote the *Hadwiger number*, that is, the maximum $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$.

We say that a finite, simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is *contraction-sensitive* if collapsing any $2$ non-adjacent points increases the Hadwiger number. An example of such a graph [is the icosahedron](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325655/contracting-non-adjacent-points-in-the-icosahedron).

Is there an established term for what I call "contraction-sensitive", and is there any literature on it? In particular it would be interesting to know whether there such graphs that are in addition vertex-critical (that is, removing any vertex decreases the chromatic number).