# Contraction criticality and edge-adding criticality for Hadwiger number

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected, simple, finite, undirected graph. The *Hadwiger number* $\eta(G)$ is the maximum integer $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$.

We say that $G$ is *contraction-Hadwiger-critical (cHc)* if contracting any pair of non-adjacent vertices increases the Hadwiger number. (The icosahedron graph is an [example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325655/contracting-non-adjacent-points-in-the-icosahedron) of a contraction-critical graph.)

Morever, we call $G$ *edge-Hadwiger-critical (eHc)* if adding an edge between any pair of non-adjacent vertices increases the Hadwiger number.

It is not hard to show that any cHc graph is eHc.

Does the converse hold?

Comment: No, $K_n$ minus an edge is eHc but not cHc.

Comment: Thanks - will delete the question